# NoSQL store re-orderable list of elements

Tags: database, nosql

I have a NoSQL setup as follows:

```
UserId : ContentId : OrderId
User1  : Content1  : 0 
User1  : Content2  : 1
User2  : Content3  : 0
User2  : Content4  : 1
User2  : Content5  : 2
User2  : Content6  : 3
User2  : Content7  : 4
```

I get the list of User2 items sorted by order which

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE UserId = 'User2' SORT BY OrderId DESC
```

which results in

```
UserId : ContentId : OrderId
User2  : Content3  : 0
User2  : Content4  : 1
User2  : Content5  : 2
User2  : Content6  : 3
User2  : Content7  : 4
```

Great! Now I want to swap so that the table looks like this:

```
UserId : ContentId : OrderId
User2  : Content3  : 0
User2  : Content6  : 3
User2  : Content4  : 1
User2  : Content5  : 2
User2  : Content7  : 4
```

So I move `Content6` to after `Content3` and before `Content4`. The drawback now is that to update the `OrderId` I have to update every row after `Content3` resulting in multiple writes to the datastore.

What is a better way of doing this in a NoSQL database?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a more sophisticated algorithm, you can create a big gap between the keys and then you could move item from one place to inbetween other keys.

After a while some spaces may run out so the algorithm in this case will have to normalize the table and even the gaps between the keys, resulting in a one time procedure which will be a bit heavier on the database. this can be done periodically or on demand when you detect that you are running/ran out of space for example.

So the original table would look like:

Before

```
UserId : ContentId : OrderId
User2  : Content3  : 0
User2  : Content4  : 1000
User2  : Content5  : 2000
User2  : Content6  : 3000
User2  : Content7  : 4000
```

After

```
UserId : ContentId : OrderId
User2  : Content3  : 0
User2  : Content6  : 500
User2  : Content4  : 1000
User2  : Content5  : 2000
User2  : Content7  : 4000
```

Comment: I have to say that if this is for a displayable list that won't have more than a few dozens of items and you don't expect thousands of updates to the items order per day then the multiple writes to the datastore is probably negligible performance-wise, so you shouldn't bother over this.

Another way to solve this would be to store items in a linked list fashion, so each item points to the next, then you get fast performance for moving items on the expense of the performance of scanning the entire table.

Comment: Thanks, I had considered a linked list solution, but then how do I easily do an ORDER BY query that will extract the rows in order of OrderId?

Comment: Yes, order by won't work on link list, you'll have to do a lot of database work or in memory work to sort the rows when you read them, so with linked list you get fast move vs slow read.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in massive updating in a good NoSQL solution, as under the hood an update looks like an append to a file which is commonly called Write Ahead Log. For example, if you issue 1000000 updates and each of them is, say, 32 bytes in size, then it will result in just writing 32MB to a file which can be done even on magnetic disks in less than 1 second. Moreover if all of those updates are in one transaction then this should be exactly one write/writev syscall with a large buffer.